# Add payment logo and facebook in the footer

Tags: magento-1.9, footer, cms-block

I would like to add payment logo in my footer, and also to add a facebook block in my footer. Exist it an extension?

Comment: what you mean by footer block?

Comment: A facebook block as pictured on the site that lets click on I like

Answer (score 4):

Good way of adding payment logo and social icon in footer ,so that  admin can easily change these images:

- Create a static block from admin and add image there.
- Call that static block in your footer.phtml located at:

> app/design/frontend/your_package/your_template/template/page/html

- You can call static block by using below code:

> $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_id')->toHtml();

Replace block_id with your static block id.

Comment: In the footer.phtml It is necessary to add the code $this-> getLayout()-> createBlock('cms/block')-> setBlockId ('block_id')-> toHtml();

Comment: Yes, if you want to call your static block in footer then you have to call in this way. In this way you can change payment logo and other images in footer from admin whenever you want.

Comment: <?php /*
                    <?php if ($tmp = $this->getChildHtml('block_footer_payment')): ?>
                     <div class="item float-right block_footer_payment"><?php echo $tmp; ?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    
                    <?php if ($tmp = $this->getChildHtml('store_switcher')): ?>
                     <div class="item float-right"><?php echo $tmp; ?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    */ ?>

Comment: I find this code in my footer.phtml and block static was already create. I remove the comments but it does not display my means of payment

Comment: There isn't any static block calling in your code , that's actually calling of child phtml file. Please use my suggestion of calling static block, this will be a good way of putting icons and images in footer.

Comment: Hello, I create my static block in my admin of magento. I go in my footer.phtml. I have my block call using its code. But it does not appear on my front office

Comment: Have you replaced block_id with your static block id ?

Comment: Yes exemple :  $this-> getLayout()-> createBlock('cms/block')-> setBlockId ('logopayement ')-> toHtml(); . I wonder if not missing: <? php? >

Comment: this is php code ,then it's obvious to add php tag

Answer (score 0):

Hi cam do this  easy at some code;

first out images at `skin/frontend/YOUR Package/Your Template/images/`

Then Goto `app/design/frontend/YOUR Package/Your Template/template/page/html` and open `footer.phtml`

**Call this images using code:**

```
<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/yourimagename.imageextension') ;>
```

Comment: Image path only displayed instead of the image. How to solve this?